# Finding a string within a string

Tags: java, string, split, substring

How can i show this? substring?split? ...

but it's maybe dynamic !!!

```
String str = "SET ENCALSUP=NOENCR&GSMV2,MAXNCELL=16,TDTMWIND=5,MAXLAPDMN=5,EENHDTMSUP=DISABLED,T3197=4,PAGCOORCLB=DISABLED,DGRSTRGYBCNT=DISABLED,PAGQOVLIND=0;";
```

this output (EENHDTMSUP=DISABLED):

just this

```
DISABLED
```

Thanks ...

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Do you want to show each key->value pair?

Comment: You haven't specified on what criteria the sub-string should be selected.  Currently the answer to your question is `System.out.println("EENHDTMSUP=DISABLED")`.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear.  Do you just need to know the value of "EENHDMSUP"?

If so, something like:

```
int start = myString.indexOf("EENHDTMSUP=");
String substr = myString.subString(start,myString.indexOf(',',start);
System.out.println(substr);
```

Would probably work.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str.substring(4),",");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: Your first tokenizer.nextToken() will display this:

"SET ENCALSUP=NOENCR&GSMV2". I think he wants the "SET" removed.

Comment: I had removed the "SET" with the substring on the string passed to the tokenizer constructor.  This shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Although it doesn't look like this is what the poster was asking for.  Oh well.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed your substring(4) in your StringTokenizer constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by "but it's maybe dynamic."
But if the string always follows that format and "EENHDTMSUP=DISABLED" stays at that same index in the string, then you can use:

```
String output = str.Split(',')[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try?

```
String[] strings = str.split(",");

for (String s:strings) {
    if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith("set ")) {
        s = s.substring("set ".length());
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Using regular expressions of course ;)